# Infinite UICollectionview with UIPageControl

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift4, infinite-scroll, uipagecontrol

In below given code I can simply infinitely scroll through the cells. The page control also seems to be working at least while scrolling forward (to the right of screen). But frankly, when I scroll to the left, I see weird index path jump of 3 items (by the way my data source has 3 items for test purposes). In the screen I notice nothing wrong. But page control seems to be freezing for a moment and starts to work again but with a shift and shows wrong dot for the cell. Any Ideas? Thanks for any help...

```
import UIKit

class HomeHeaderCell: CategoryCell {

    private let cellId = "cellId"
    private var timer: Timer?
    private let infiniteSize = 1000
    private var onlyOnce = true

    // ...

    let pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50))
        let pc = UIPageControl(frame: rect)
        pc.currentPage = 0
        pc.numberOfPages = 3
        pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
        pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
        pc.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return pc
    }()

    override func setupViews() {

        addSubview(baseCollectionView)
        addSubview(pageControl)


        baseCollectionView.delegate = self
        baseCollectionView.dataSource = self
        baseCollectionView.register(HeaderCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        baseCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        baseCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        baseCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = true

        baseCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false


        baseCollectionView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)
        pageControl.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    }


    @objc func autoScroll() {
        guard let currentItemNumber = baseCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first?.item  else { return }
        let nextItemNumber = currentItemNumber + 1
        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(item: nextItemNumber, section: 0)
        baseCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: nextIndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        stopTimer()
    }
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        startTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(autoScroll), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return infiniteSize
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell

        // Maybe can be done more elegantly...
        if let foods = foodCategory?.foods {
            let numberOfFood = indexPath.item % foods.count
            cell.food = foods[numberOfFood]
            pageControl.currentPage = numberOfFood
            print(numberOfFood)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if onlyOnce  {
            let middleIndex = IndexPath(item: Int (infiniteSize / 2), section: 0)
            baseCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: middleIndex, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
            startTimer()
            onlyOnce = false
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    private class HeaderCell: ItemCell {

        override func setupViews() {
            addSubview(imageView)

            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
            imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

            imageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you cut down your code to only show the bits relevant to the problem. Like when you are setting the page control values. There is too much code to filter through it.

Comment: Use FSPagerView pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own question. Here is the code you should be applying. First two methods are UIScrollView methods that comes free with UICollectionView, which by the way a subclass of UIScrollView. updatePageControl method is the one that I wrote just to keep code clean and simple. Hope this helps...

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updatePageControl(scrollView: scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    updatePageControl(scrollView: scrollView)
}
func updatePageControl(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width)
    guard let count = foodCategory?.foods?.count else {return}
    let currentPageNumber = Int(pageNumber) % count
    pageControl.currentPage = currentPageNumber
}
```